# Invalid Component Netbeans Java Swing /Maven

Tags: java, maven, swing, netbeans

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XUNa.jpg)
My project was working perfectly, and then somehow when I opened netbeans I was surprised to see this exception:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.mycompany.mma.CustomTable
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:678)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.CreationFactory.createDefaultInstance(CreationFactory.java:155)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.createBeanInstance(RADComponent.java:227)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.initInstance(RADComponent.java:166)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:761)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:949)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:805)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:949)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:805)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:949)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:484)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:260)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:327)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:268)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.doEventAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.readAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:77)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.LazyMutexImplementation.readAccess(LazyMutexImplementation.java:71)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:231)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:251)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:324)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:436)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:256)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:64)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:245)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycompany.mma.CustomTable.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:665)
    ... 37 more
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.mycompany.mma.CustomTable
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:678)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.CreationFactory.createDefaultInstance(CreationFactory.java:155)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.createBeanInstance(RADComponent.java:227)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.initInstance(RADComponent.java:166)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:761)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:949)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:805)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:949)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:805)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:949)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:805)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:949)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:484)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:260)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:327)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:268)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.doEventAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.readAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:77)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.LazyMutexImplementation.readAccess(LazyMutexImplementation.java:71)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:231)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:251)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:324)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:436)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:256)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:64)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:245)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycompany.mma.CustomTable.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:665)
    ... 39 more
```

I created a custom table and a custom button with slide effect animation. It was working perfectly, but then this happened

This is the code for the custom table:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import static java.awt.Color.black;
import static java.awt.Color.red;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Haythem
 */
public class CustomTable extends JTable{
        
    public CustomTable(int a , int b ,int c){    
        getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new CustomTableHeader(a,b,c));
        getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,70));
        setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomTableCell());
        setRowHeight(45);
        setBorder(null);
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(10, 100, 10));
this.isCellEditable(-1, -1);
this.setEditingRow(-1);
this.setEditingColumn(-1);
this.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);

        
    }
    
   private class CustomTableHeader extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

        public CustomTableHeader(int a , int b , int c) {
            setcolor(a, b, c);
        }
        
        int l,k,m;
        public void setcolor(int a , int b , int c){
       this.l=a;
       this.k=b;
       this.m=c;
        }
       @Override
       public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table , Object o , boolean b , boolean b1 , int i , int i2){
           Component c= super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, o, b1, b1, i, i2);
           c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(l,k,m));
           c.setFont(new Font("AraAlmBon",Font.BOLD,14));
           return c;
       }
        
    }
    private class CustomTableCell extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
           Component c=super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
            if(isCellSelected(row, column)){
               if(row%2==0){
                   c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(33,103,153));
               }
               else{
                    c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(29,86,127));
               }
           }
           else{
                if(row%2==0){
                    c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(50,50,50));
               }
               else{
                    c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(30,30,30));
               }
           }
           c.setForeground(new Color(200,200,200));
           setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,5,0,5));
           return c;
        }
        
    }
  
    private class CustomTablef extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/OverriddenMethodBody
        }
    }
}
```

This is the custom button code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

/**
 *
 * @author Haythem
 */
public class Button extends JButton{
    public float getAnimate() {
        return animate;
    }

    /**
     * @param animate the animate to set
     */
    public void setAnimate(float animate) {
        this.animate = animate;
        repaint();
    }
    private float animate;
  public Button(){
      setOpaque(false);
      setContentAreaFilled(false);
  }
    @Override
public void paint(Graphics grphcs){
Graphics2D g;
g=(Graphics2D)grphcs.create();
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
double width=getWidth();
double height=getHeight();
double x=animate*width-width;
Area area=new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x,0,width,height,0,0));
g.setColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 110, 50));
g.fill(area);
g.dispose();
    super.paint(grphcs);
}
}
```

I tried to remove the component and try again. It worked for a while and then the issue resurfaced.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycompany.mma.CustomTable.<init>()

Comment: Since you provided a non-default constructor for your `CustomTable` class, the compiler did not implicitly declare a default (no args) constructor on your behalf. See [section 8.8.9 Default Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) of the Java Language Specification. That resulted in the `newInstance()` call (shown at the bottom of your stack trace) failing with a `NoSuchMethodException` because `CustomTable()` does not exist. Consider providing an answer to your own question once you understand the problem.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you very Much for the quick and straight to the point answer adding a Default Constructor fixed the issue

Comment: @Lemonjuice That's good. Now consider writing an answer to your own question, and accepting it. Answered questions are always more helpful to the community.

Comment: O/T: Two misguided people voting to close this question without comment because it _"Needs debugging details"_ even though the question included their code and a relevant stack trace, which was all that was needed to resolve the issue?! Over zealous close voters do more harm than good on SO, and surely drive new posters away.

Answer (score 2):

The newInstance() call failed throwing an exception (NoSuchMethodException) Because no default constructor for the custom class was found thus what i did was create a default constructor and that fixed the issue